# No access to a variable in the MongoDB Shell when executing a js-file

Tags: javascript, file, variables, mongodb, execute

I wrote a simple function in a js-file and would like to execute it in MongoDB. My code looks like the following:

```
var test = function() {
    db.foo.insert({name:"huiboo"});
};
```

My problem is that when I try to execute the script like

```
./mongo server:27017/dbname test.js
```

and start the MongoDB shell right after, then I won't have access to the variable "test" in the MongoDB Shell and can't execute the function.

But if I do it like this

```
./mongo server:27017/dbname --shell test.js
```

then I do have access to the variable "test" and everything works like it supposed to do. But I don't want to start the shell after executing the file. I rather would like to be able to execute the variable "test" in an already running MongoDB Shell.

So my question: Is it possible to have access to variables in the MongoDB Shell without adding the option "--shell"?

note: I use MongoDB 2.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, every instance of the mongo shell has it's own JS scope. You can however store the JS function server-side which will allow you to invoke it in any shell instance :

```
db.system.js.save( { _id : "test" , value : function(){ db.foo.insert({name:"huiboo"}); } } );
```

For details : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside